# Integration with terraform go-SDK

Tags: go, sdk, terraform

I am trying to integrate **Terraform** go-SDK with my go-code where I already have an terraform template file and I need to create the infrastructure by importing that file to the go-SDK. I am not able to find any related documents. I tried with the **[godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform)** for terraform. With a little understanding, I tried to implement a simple terraform template. My terraform template file is,

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "xxxx"
  secret_key = "xxxx"
  region     = "xxxx"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-xxxx"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

 # The name of our SSH keypair.
  key_name      = "xxxx" 

 # Security groupID
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-xxxx"]

 #Subnet ID
  subnet_id = "subnet-xxxx"

}
```

I tried via commandLine and I am able to bring up an instance with this file.
I tried the same via my go-code. My understanding is that I need to create a **Context** in order to **apply** it. For creating a **Context,** I need a **module.Tree.** So I tried creating a **module.Tree** with **config.Config.** I imported the above **terraform** template file to my go-code to create a **config** and a **tree**. My go-code looks like,

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config"
   "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config/module"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   con, err := config.LoadFile(path to .tf file)
   fmt.Println("Config: ", con)
   fmt.Println("Error: ", err)

   fmt.Println("Validate: ", con.Validate())

   tree := module.NewTree("testTree", con)
   fmt.Println("Tree: ", tree.String())
}
```

When I execute my code, I am not getting any errors for loading the config from file, or validating the same. But I am getting the output as "tree not loaded",

```
Output:
Config:  &{ <nil> <nil> [] [0xc4201cd0c0] [0xc4201f03c0] [] [] [] []}
Error:  <nil>
Validate:  <nil>
Tree:  testTree  not loaded
```

Can someone help me out to implement this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terraform doesn't have a "go-SDK" per say, it really isn't designed to be used as a library. Automated systems using terraform execute the terraform binary.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JimB. So should I go with executing the terraform binary to perform operations? Will that be efficient enough?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient enough"? Starting a new process isn't inefficient, and terraform will need to start more subprocess anyway. If you want to see how things work, you need to start at the top in main and walk your way down. There's a lot that needs to happen. Also note that because this isn't intended as a library, there is no compatibility contract for any of these APIs, and they can and will change at any time.

Comment: Yes that's right. I started automating it via binary. Thanks for your response.